# Dealing with class multiple input in web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[image]

Hi, I am trying to scrape the value ="36", but I don't know how to deal with the fact there are multiple inputs of the class.

My code is the following:

```
## cdkitchen.com
url= 'http://www.cdkitchen.com/recipes/recs/32/Snowball_Cookies_II54545.shtml'
r = requests.get(url)
page_body = r.text
soup=BeautifulSoup(page_body, 'html.parser')
stat= soup.find('div', class_='col-md-4 col-sm-4 mb-20')
for a in stat.find('form', class_='change-servs-form'):
    print(a.get_value())
```

the get_value() doesn't work, I tried some other things but I am blocked, is there an easy way to specify which input we want to scrape?

Comment: `but I don't know how to deal with the fact there are multiple inputs of the class.` Can you clarify what this means? What inputs are you referring to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you properly specify a class in beautifulsoup `find` method 
`{'class': 'classname'}`

Also, use `soup.get('attribute')` to get any attribute from the given tag (`value` for this matter).

Working code:

```
stat = soup.find('div', {'class': 'col-md-4 col-sm-4 mb-20'})
for a in stat.find('form', {'class': 'change-servs-form'}):
    print(a.get('value'))
```

> 36

Note: I prefer CSS selectors but I didn't want to temper with your code all that much. You should look into that :)

**EDIT**

Using CSS selectors, getting `value` attr from each `input` tag inside the `form`

```
stat = soup.find('form', {'class': 'change-servs-form'})
input_tags = stat.select('input')
for a in input_tags:
    print(a.get('value'))
```

> 36
>   21411
>   change servings
>   reset

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be something like below. Using css selectors:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('http://www.cdkitchen.com/recipes/recs/32/Snowball_Cookies_II54545.shtml')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
item_name = '\n'.join([item['value'] for item in soup.select('.change-servs-form input')])
print(item_name)
```

Output:

```
36
21411
change servings
reset
```